# How to keep empty if there is no value in column using if else

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, validation

My project is about find null values in a dataframe and show column names which exist null values . they are showing in column `['null_columns']`

I want to keep the `['null_columns']` as " no data " if there are no any null values exist in that row.

I tried this code for that

```
def my_function(row): 
    
    null = df.isnull()
    print(null)
    null_columns = df.apply(lambda row: [str(x) for x in row.index[row.isnull()]], axis=1)
    null_columns_names = df.apply(lambda row: ', '.join(str(x) for x in row.index[row.isnull()]), axis=1)
    
    if any(null):
        
        df['null_columns'] = "The value in " + null_columns_names +" is Null "
        
    else:
        df['null_columns'] = "no data"
    
    return df

df.apply(my_function, axis=1)

df
```

And my results column looks like this:

```
0    The value in eNodeB Name,  Frequency band, DL ...
1            The value in VoLTE Drop Rate%(%) is Null 
2            The value in VoLTE Drop Rate%(%) is Null 
3    The value in DL User Thrp(kbps)(kbit/s), UL Us...
4                               The value in  is Null  ## in this row there are no any null value. but 
5                The value in  Frequency band is Null       it is not showing as "no data"
6                The value in  Frequency band is Null
```

Comment: It is very hard to figure out what you are trying to do, and how your data look like. Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think @kalharaIET is wondering why the function does not enter the `else` condition even if there are no `null` values in the row.

Answer (score 0):

This might just be an error with variable names `row` and `df`. I think you want to apply this function for each row, but you use

```
null = df.isnull()
...
if any(null):
```

instead of

```
null = row.isnull()
...
if any(null):
```

As there is at least one `null` in your `df` variable, you always enter the first condition, even if the row contains no `null`.

PS: You should be able to show columns with `null` using the following command: `df.isna().sum() > 0`
If you want to drop rows with `null` you can use `df.dropna(axis=1)`